# While using jenkins API, getting a failure on reconfig_job

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am using jenkins rest API to recurse through jobs and then reconfigure this one. All methods work except one. He's is my code :

```
def get_server_instance():
    jenkins_url = 'xxxx'
    #server = Jenkins(jenkins_url, username = '', password = '')
    # Connect to instance - username and password are optional
    server = jenkins.Jenkins(jenkins_url, username = '', password = '')
    return server


def get_job_details():
    # Refer Example #1 for definition of function 'get_server_instance'
    server = get_server_instance()
    for job in server.get_jobs_list():
        if job == "GithubMigration":
            configuration = server.get_job(job).get_config().encode('utf-8')
            #server.reconfig_job(job, configuration)
            if server.has_job("GithubMigration"):
                server.reconfig_job('GithubMigration', config_xml)
```

It gets my configuration.xml, find the job as well but fails on **server.reconfig_job('GithubMigration', config_xml)** with the error , AttributeError: 'Jenkins' object has no attribute 'reconfig_job'

when obviously this functions exists in the jenkins rest API and yes I'm importing jenkins, from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins .

Edit 1 - I uninstalled Jenkinsapi and have only python-jenkins module and now it fails even before saying

***AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Jenkins' for line : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Jenkins'***

Any ideas?

Edit 2 :

I tries solely python-jenkins API and tried their own example as you see here http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example.html

```
import jenkins
j = jenkins.Jenkins('http://your_url_here', 'username', 'password')
j.get_jobs()
j.create_job('empty', jenkins.EMPTY_CONFIG_XML)
j.disable_job('empty')
j.copy_job('empty', 'empty_copy')
j.enable_job('empty_copy')
j.reconfig_job('empty_copy', jenkins.RECONFIG_XML)
```

Even this fails at jenkins.Jenkins with attribute error at Jenkins - No module.

I am pretty sure the API is broken.

Comment: Where did you find this method? Can you add link to documentation of `reconfig_job` method?

Comment: @Chemik - If you visit the following link on the official documentation - https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html and search for reconfig_job, you will find it there.

Comment: Ok, but I cannot find `get_jobs_list()` nor `get_job(job)` methods. The problem is that you are mixing `python-jenkins` and `jenkinsapi` [(docs here)](https://jenkinsapi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). You should `import jenkins` not `from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins`. btw you should change your password, this great site is keeping history of post edits ;)

Comment: already did that (password), but let me get back to you with my other findings.

Comment: @Chemik - check out my new edit.

Comment: I am pretty sure your installation of python-jenkins is broken. My recommendation is to uninstall it and reinstall using `pip` (see documentation)

Comment: @Chemik - I did that 4 times already w/wo documentation. Did you give the example they have a quick try and see if it works for you ?

Comment: Yes of course. Try this: `print jenkins.__file__` right after import and check if it is same as your install path of module. I bet you have file jenkins.py in directory where is your script.

Comment: @Chemik - /Users/kaulk/Desktop/JenkinsWrap/jenkins.py - this is what that printed. Still not sure what the error is. In any case I was able to get past that problem using jenkinsapi. I have another question and you might be able to answer. How do I access the workspace of any job in jenkins through the jenkinsapi ? I need to access a file within the workspace...

Comment: If you have another question please create new one.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your script is probably importing wrong module. You can check it as follows:

```
import jenkins
print jenkins.__file__
```

If printed path is other than installation path of jenkins module (eg. `C:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\jenkins\__init__.pyc`), then you should check pythonpath:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

Common problem is existence of python script with same name as imported module in current directory, which is at the first place in search path `''`.

For more info on import order see [module search path](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path)

Answer (score 2):

Following [@Chemik answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267884/while-using-jenkins-api-getting-a-failure-on-reconfig-job#answer-28333484), I realized that the script I wrote was named `jenkins.py` and it was conflicting with python-jenkins import.

The library isn't broken. Check your script name.

Answer (score 1):

had to add another solution, while running the same command

```
server = jenkins.Jenkins(jenkins_url, username = '', password = '')
```

i got the error:

```
'jenkins' has no attribute 'Jenkins'
```

my mistake was when installing the package, i installed package "jenkins" and the package i was needed is "python-jenkins".
docs can be found:
[python-jenkins docs](https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html)

so what i had to do is just

```
pip install python-jenkins
```