# Creating Jenkins Job using python API

Tags: python, jenkins

I am very new to Jenkins and am trying to create a build job using the python API. I am using the following code that I found in the docs: https://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#example-3-working-with-jenkins-jobs

But I am struggling to get pass this line of code

```
server.create_job(job_name, Jenkins.EMPTY_CONFIG_XML)
```

It is giving me an error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Jenkins' has no attribute 'EMPTY_CONFIG_XML'
```

Am I supposed to be specifying a file path to the `config.xml`?
I am just a bit confused on how the server creates the job using `EMPTY_CONFIG_XML`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: According to the documentation you linked, `EMPTY_CONFIG_XML` is a property of `jenkins` (lowercase), not `Jenkins`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first [from where you are importing your `jenkins` module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28333484/6309):

```
import jenkins
print jenkins.__file__
```

Check also if the connection is working (from the first part of [Get version of Jenkins](http://python-jenkins.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html))

```
import jenkins

server = jenkins.Jenkins('http://localhost:8080', username='myuser', password='mypassword')
user = server.get_whoami()
version = server.get_version()
print('Hello %s from Jenkins %s' % (user['fullName'], version))
```

You have a similar error [pending in this issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-jenkins/+bug/1605491).

The string "`EMPTY_FOLDER_XML`" [only appears in](https://github.com/openstack/python-jenkins/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=EMPTY_FOLDER_XML&type=) in [`doc/source/examples.rst`](https://github.com/openstack/python-jenkins/blob/828eb92c481898e574f4729d030a7ea5b850a0d2/doc/source/examples.rst#L184) so it is possible it is an "example" value.

The [`tests/jobs/test_create.py`](https://github.com/openstack/python-jenkins/blob/c54c98a9f02c1cd56c3b3dcb81796026c345060a/tests/jobs/test_create.py#L8-L18) uses

```
self.j.create_job(u'Test Job', self.config_xml)
```

with [`tests/jobs/base.py`](https://github.com/openstack/python-jenkins/blob/c54c98a9f02c1cd56c3b3dcb81796026c345060a/tests/jobs/base.py#L9-L13) defining config_xml as:

```
config_xml = """
    <matrix-project>
        <actions/>
        <description>Foo</description>
    </matrix-project>"""
```

So you can use a similar approach in order to define your own empty or minimal `config.xml`.

The [OP J. H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7975294/j-h) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43960401/creating-jenkins-job-using-python-api/43960497?noredirect=1#comment75071771_43960497) to the simple fix:

> Simply just had to install `python-jenkins`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!! I managed to get it working. It was a silly mistake. Simply just had to `install python-jenkins`

Comment: @J.H Great! i have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.